# How to return IDs that are in each table

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

How to I write a SQL script that return all the site IDs that are in all my tables:

Tables in this image:

[image]

And this is what I want returned:

[image]

...because only site 1 & 2 are in all four tables.

Database: SQL Azure (but I don't think that matters)

Comment: Is INTERSECT supported?

Comment: Take a look at `JOIN` it will return common ID's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select SiteID
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.SiteID = t2.SiteID 
join table3 t3 on t2.SiteID = t3.SiteID
join table4 t4 on t3.SiteID = t4.SiteID
join table5 t5 on t4.SiteID = t5.SiteID;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `join`:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id join
     table3 t3
     on t1.id = t3.id join
     table4 t4
     on t1.id = t4.id;
```

Comment: @jarlh . . . `intersect` is a perfectly reasonable solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's the same for all database engines, but in `postgres` you can do something like this.

`select table1.siteid from table1,table2,table3 where (table1.siteid=table2.siteid) and (table1.siteid=table3.siteid);`

Comment: Yes, that's standard SQL, old-school joins. (But it's good programming practice do new style, explicit JOIN's.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SQL Server supports INTERSECT operator. It is the easiest way to write it:

select SiteID from table1
intersect
select SiteID from table2
intersect
select SiteID from table3....

This will get translated to appropriate joins.